# Magento 2.0 certification?

Tags: magento2, certification

We are looking for the official Magento 2 certification.

When you guys are going to have a Magento 2 certification program?

Answer (score 6):

@Nilesh Word is that the first offering of M2 certification will be at Imagine next year. Magento U is already offering a Magento 2 Developer Bootcamp (https://magento.com/training/catalog/fundamentals-of-magento-2-development-instructor-led-ondemand) which has a knowledge assessment component included (https://magento.com/training/catalog/catalog/product/view/id/31670/s/knowledge-assessment-magento2-fundamentals/12962). This assessment appears to be the preliminary work needed to structure the M2 developer certification.

I just took the bootcamp in New York a few weeks ago. I also took the assessment. The assessment focused entirely on the new features and facilities available in M2.

Currently, the assessment is the closest thing you can get to a M2 certification. Again, I was told directly that the M2 certification will be offered at next year's Imagine.

Comment: My gosh 3 grands ? I'd rather wait for the certification to come out

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism Yea, I was fortunate enough for my employer to cover the cost. The bootcamp format is pretty cool though, literally only writing code and working through exercises, and then the assessment (of course). Besides cost, this is what's available at the moment.

Answer (score 4):

Magento 2 certification is not available yet.

You can check out this forum post: https://community.magento.com/t5/Off-Topic/Magento-2-certification-exams/td-p/176

Basically:

> The full Magento 2 certification won't happen until after everyone has
>   real-world experience with Magento 2, as it's based on that real-world
>   experience that none of us have yet.

Also check the official certification page: https://magento.com/training/catalog/certification

When a Magento 2 certification will be available that's where you'll find it.

Answer (score 4):

Latest news about the developer certifications:

- Magento 2 Certified Solutions Specialist - available since Oktober
  2017
- Magento 2 Certified Developer Exam - March 2018
- Magento 2 Certified Front-End Developer Exam - May 2018
- Magento 2 Associate Certified Developer Exam - June 2018

Source: https://twitter.com/benmarks/status/949499339675611137

Answer (score 2):

I was told the Magento 2 certification will be out in 2017. I don't know if they are going to make it before Imagine 2017 in april, but they certainly don't want to wait until Imagine 2018, because they also feel the pressure of the need for official certification and do not want to postpone it.

The "real-world experience" is one of the things that Magento has been waiting for, but there are more reasons. The good old Magento 1 exam was accommodated within a system that involved a lot of work. Magento is now in the process of partnering up with a different company to facilitate the exams.

Also I think Magento has waited for Magento 2 to "settle" a bit more. In the beginning there might have been some faulty parts in the system that they would correct first or add new features into Magento 2 (2.1?), which all could affect any certification course and would therefore need changing in the course materials ("Did you do Magento 2 2.0 or 2.1 certification?").

Answer (score 2):

MAGENTO 2 CERTIFIED SOLUTION SPECIALIST exam now available now please check below link

https://u.magento.com/certified-magento2-solution-specialist

You can also find study guide for Magento 2 exam from this [link](https://magento-u.magento.com/magento-u/downloads/M2%20MCSS%20Exam%20Study%20Guide.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED:After Acquiring Magento by Adobe[21 August 2020]**

*Magento 2 Certified Professional Developer exam => AD0-E703 Adobe Certified Expert - Magento Commerce Developer*

It is now available :
[Register](https://spark.adobe.com/page/OwpmK2JcACwhl/)

[Complete Exam Guide](https://spark.adobe.com/page/RxKLtZiTNdnn3/)

Comment: You are welcome! LOL

Answer (score 1):

**Latest news about the developer certifications:updated [21 August 2020]**:

Total 8 Certifications are now renamed by Adobe:

- Magento 2 Certified Solutions Specialist =>  **[AD0-E700]:** *Adobe Certified Expert Magento Commerce Business Practitioner*  [Details](https://spark.adobe.com/page/87jLctNB6KxM0/)
- Magento 2 Certified Front-End Developer Exam =>  **[AD0-E701]:** *Adobe Certified Expert-Magento Commerce Front-End Developer* [Details](https://spark.adobe.com/page/lJWBfPhvp5npA/)
- Magento 2 Associate Certified Developer Exam =>  **[AD0-E702]:** *Adobe Certified Professional—Magento Commerce Developer*  [Details](https://spark.adobe.com/page/saM506xrYKi0p/)
- Magento 2 Certified Developer Exam =>  **[AD0-E703]:** *Adobe Certified Expert - Magento Commerce Developer* [Details](https://spark.adobe.com/page/OwpmK2JcACwhl/)
- Magento 2 Certified Full-Stack Developer =>  **[AD0-E704]:** *Adobe Certified Master Magento Commerce Architect* [Details](https://spark.adobe.com/page/PTidDHsT5JgyB/)
- Magento 2 Certified Professional Javascript Developer  =>  **[AD0-E705]:** *Adobe Certified Expert-Magento Commerce JavaScript Developer*  [Details](https://spark.adobe.com/page/ZDus3If2u1rQf/)
- Magento 2 Certified Professional Cloud Developer =>  **[AD0-E706]:** *Adobe Certified Expert-Magento Commerce Cloud Developer* [available since June 2018] [Details](https://spark.adobe.com/page/GrkbPktpWMkkb/)
- **[Adobe AD0-E707]** Adobe Certified Expert Magento Commerce Order Management Developer [Details](https://spark.adobe.com/page/K2Wjl6Na3BY0h/)

Answer (score 0):

AD0-E702: Adobe Certified Professional—Magento Commerce Developer exam is now available for Register.

[Register Here](https://spark.adobe.com/page/saM506xrYKi0p/)

[Complete Exam Preparation guide](https://spark.adobe.com/page/ClHLYMaUjTUfa/)

Answer (score 0):

As per the NDA of Adobe Certification policy.
We are expected to keep the contents of the examination confidential.
Failure to adhere to those terms will forfeit our
credential and prohibit us from participating in our certification program.

From my past experience of certification attempts,
I strongly believe that behind NDA there are hidden agendas.

Adobe Will never allow 3rd party candidates, So that they will pull the clients easily.

NO.1 Suppose you are asked to disable/remove the customer review related functionalities. You can
not disable the review module directly because the customer module depends on it. What is the
possible way to remove all HTML outputs of the review module, from the frontend and backend? :
(A). Turn-off Review module output globally by extending
<Magento_install_dir>/vendor/magento/module-backend/etc/config.xml
(B). Turn-off Review module output globally by extending
<Magento_install_dir>/vendor/magento/module-backend/etc/module.xml
(C). Create plugin or Override the class \Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock and
toHtml() method, and implement the logic to return empty data in case of review module's block
instance is present.
(D). Create plugin or Override the class \Magento\Backend\Block\Template and isOutputEnabled()
method, and implement the logic to return false value in case of review module's block instance is
present.
Answer: A

Answer (score 0):

A Magento site is experiencing an issue where a fatal out of memory error occurs during a
custom bulk catalog import process. Here is the code:

(A). Call Magento\Framework\Data\Collection: setMemoryLimit to increase PHP's memory limit
(B). Inject an instance Of
Uagento\Catalog\model\ResourceModel\Product\IteratingCollectionFactory into your code instead

(C). Use a \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\iterator to walk through the collection row-
by-row

(D). UseMagento\Model\Entity\Collection\AbstractCollection: :setPage to iterate through the
collection in chunks
Answer: B,C

Answer (score 0):

After enable the content security policy in a magento site, you see below warnings/errors in
the browser console. "[Report Only] Refused to load the script 'https://cdn.jquery.com/jquery.js'
because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src
assets.adobedtm.com".What could be the standard fix of this problem?
(A). Add etc/csp_whitelist.xml in a custom module and whitelist it under policy id="script-src"
(B). Add etc/csp_whitelist.xml in a custom module and whitelist it under policy id="link-src"
(C). Add etc/config.xml in a custom module and set report only to 1, to let the browser load all script
urls without error.
(D). Disable the module Magento_Csp to let the browser load all script urls without error.
Answer: A

Answer (score 0):

You want to add an additional validation rule, allowed_symbols, to the telephone field on the
Checkout Address form. You have created the validation rule and added it to the Magento_Ui/js/lib
validation validator instance.

IT Certification Guaranteed, The Easy Way!

2

What action is required to complete the task?
(A). Add your validation rule name to the Magento\checkout\Model\validation\Pool class,
$validationRules array parameter with the key telephone
(B). Create a mixin on the validateShippinginformation method to add your rule
(C). Add your validation rule to the Magento_Checkout/js/element/validation validator instance
(D). Add the validation rule name to the checkout_index_index layout in the telephone validation
path
Answer: A