# Topics and core stuffs for Magento 2 certifications

Tags: magento2, certification, discussion

I am planning for Magento 2 certification. Do anyone expert tell me what are normal concepts to master before taking exam? i checked magento stack but didn't get desired result. Also, If possible let me know expected time of magento2 certification exam?

I already checked similar link like [Magento 2.0 certification?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/122413/29175)

Looking response from experts **regarding topics** and expected date of exam release.

My main objective is also to be aware about topics which i need to master for magento 2 certification. I have started preparation so topics response would be GREAT help for me and community members to be good in magento 2 and for certification as well.

This is not a duplicate to mentioned link in post.

Comment: https://u.magento.com/magento-2 U need to refer this

Comment: Already checked that. Looking expert opinion.

Comment: Sorry Bro @Jai. No one is expert in their own.

Comment: I am looking for topics and i question is updated.